# Jquery Ajax escapes strings despite magic_quotes_gpc = off

Tags: jquery, ajax, escaping, magic-quotes-gpc

Data I post via jQuery Ajax are being escaped even when `magic_quotes_gpc = off` on the server.

Getting data directly from `$_POST` (not using ajax) works fine, unescaped. but sending them through `ajax` escapes them.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'includes/updateDb.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    id:  $this.attr('data-id'),  
    text: $this.html()
}
});
```

`test's` -> `test\'s`

Is that a feature or a bug? How should I proceed? Strip the strings via `PHP` on the server?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data before and after?

Comment: it can be changed through 
`contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8"` or what ever you like as GeenHenk answered but i didnt think he made it clear it can be changed

Comment: @rainykeys I am not very familiarized with JSON. Does this mean the data will be only sent in this format? Because I'm having trouble accessing $_POST data this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that despite `phpinfo()` showed that `magic_quotes_gpc` were turned off, they were indeed on. It was a shared-hosting feature that caused `php.ini` to affect only the topmost folder. I didn't realize this.

Apologies and thanks for help -)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default in jQuery, in your PHP use `utf8_decode` to get the unescaped data

From [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
contentTypeString
Default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but just using `utf8_decode` doesn't help

Comment: Can you post your Ajax function?

Comment: Try switching  `text: $(this).html()` with `text: $(this).text()` or  `text: $(this).val()`. Btw, what type of element is `this`?

Comment: It's a contenteditable div, and I don't have a problem with the ajax function itself, data is sent successfully. Problem is they're escaped.

Comment: Still `.html()` does things, like strip `<script>` tags, have you tried `.text()`?

Comment: Yes. Without success :(. Still, what does `utf8_decode` even do? I'm currently using `stripslashes` which solves it, but I don't this is a clean solution. I tried changing `contentType` in the ajax function, but I can't get it to work properly.

Comment: Try adding `dataType: "text"` to your AJAX call

Comment: I'm sorry, but then I'm out of options.. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

now as you have been answered before 
the `jQuery.ajax( url [, settings] )` send only be defualt which means that it can be changed the data encoded ..  this helps preventing further issues 99% of the times ...
the defualt encoding that they use is

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

now that can be changed to any type of content let's say `text/javascript` if that was the data type your sending .
but usually what we are trying to send to php is either a string or an array .
this array needs to be encoded in some way that both languages understand ...
now from version 5.2.0 php supports the json encode which is the best way to send data from java .
so you can send a json encoded number to php which looks something like this

```
{"foo-bar": 12345}
```

and using the `json_decode()` turn it into

```
$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}' ; 
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // will return 12345
```

so officially every body just uses this format to send data from javascript to php.
for your own sake here is an example of what a php code will look like 
let's say that you send something like username and password 
the array will look something like this `{"id": "234" , "text" : "helloo,/////text////"}`

```
$posted_data = $_POST['id'];
$parsed_data = josn_decode('$posted_data');
echo $parsed_data -> {'text'}; // should print helloo,/////text////
```

Comment: first and foremost, I'm unable to post a `$_POST` data when defining either `application/json` or `text/javascript` as a `contentType` in the ajax function. Trying to access the data on the server with `$_POST` just returns an error.